# 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'to_csv'

Tags: python-3.x

> error:'NoneType' object has no attribute 'to_csv'

code:

```
import tabula
df = tabula.read_pdf(r"C:\Users\admin\Desktop\Project_1\img1.pdf", encoding='utf-8')
df.to_csv(r"C:\Users\admin\Desktop\Project_1\otuput.csv", index=False)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please add a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so it is clearer what your problem is.

Comment: Chances are that `tabula.read_pdf()` failed to read data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to print out the dataframe you read from the pdf file. This way you will notice if there was anything read from the file. To help you further there would be more information needed. For example show us the file you want to read, as there could be an error reading out it's content.
Edit:
There is another function provided by the tabula lib as well:

```
tabula.convert_into("input.pdf", "output.csv", output_format="csv")
```

this way you can directly put your dataframe into a csv file.